# Function was written to accept pairs of variables, is there a way to write them like that in python 3?

Tags: python, function, collision

The function is defined as:

```
def addVectors((angle1, length1), (angle2, length2)):
    x  = math.sin(angle1) * length1 + math.sin(angle2) * length2
    y  = math.cos(angle1) * length1 + math.cos(angle2) * length2

    angle = 0.5 * math.pi - math.atan2(y, x)
    length  = math.hypot(x, y)

    return (angle, length)
```

It is used like this:

```
def collide(p1, p2):
    dx = p1.x - p2.x
    dy = p1.y - p2.y

    dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
    if dist < p1.size + p2.size:
        angle = math.atan2(dy, dx) + 0.5 * math.pi
        total_mass = p1.mass + p2.mass

        (p1.angle, p1.speed) = addVectors((p1.angle, p1.speed*(p1.mass-p2.mass)/total_mass), (angle, 2*p2.speed*p2.mass/total_mass))
        (p2.angle, p2.speed) = addVectors((p2.angle, p2.speed*(p2.mass- p1.mass)/total_mass), (angle+math.pi, 2*p1.speed*p1.mass/total_mass))
    p1.speed *= elasticity
    p2.speed *= elasticity
```

My problem is that python 3 will only let me assign one group of parentheses to a function, but the example here uses two, and the results and the way to get them are a result of this course. I'm not sure if there is a way to fix this, or if I have to restructure the formula, which I'm really not sure I'm able to do.
Any advice?
Also, I grabbed this code from Peter Collingridges tutorial about ball physics, and all the rest is on his website http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk .
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 [removed the ability to unpack tuples in the signature of a function](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/), which is what's happening in your python 2 function.

You don't have to change any call sites if you still want to pass the arguments as tuples; you'll just have to give each tuple a name (angleAndLength1?) and use angleAndLength1[0] and angleAndLength1[1] to get the parameters.  It's probably better in this case to just remove the parentheses and pass four arguments, since you have to build a tuple in the caller anyway.

You can do this to replicate the old behavior, since tuple unpacking outside function signatures is still valid:

```
def addVectors(angleAndLength1: tuple, angleAndLength2: tuple):
  angle1, length1 = angleAndLength1
  angle2, length2 = angleAndLength2
  # the rest of your code
```

Comment: When I build a tuple of four items, I get an error from the x assignment in addVectors(), angle1 requires float. I think it has something to do with putting the names before the expressions while calling addVectors??

Comment: Not a tuple of four items.  Either four arguments (`def addVectors(angle1, length1, angle2, length2)`) or two tuples (`def addVectors(angleAndLength1, angleAndLength2)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute both tuples as a single variable each, like:

```
def addVectors(r1, r2):
    x  = math.sin(r1[0]) * r1[1] + math.sin(r2[0]) * r2[1]
    y  = math.cos(r1[0]) * r1[1] + math.cos(r2[0]) * r2[1]

    angle = 0.5 * math.pi - math.atan2(y, x)
    length  = math.hypot(x, y)

    return (angle, length)
```

Then you may use `addVectors((0,10),(30,50))`.

Comment: (r1) = addVectors((p1.speed*(p1.mass-p2.mass)/total_mass), (angle, 2*p2.speed*p2.mass/total_mass))
       (r2) = addVectors((p2.speed*(p2.mass-p1.mass)/total_mass), (angle+math.pi, 2*p1.speed*p1.mass/total_mass))                                               I did this, and I'm getting addVectors takes 2 args, 4 were given?

Comment: This is probably because you are giving four arguments instead of two.

Comment: You must use it like this: `r1 = addVectors((15,20),(33,1))`, that is, both arguments must be a tuple (enclosed in parentheses) or a list (enclosed in square brackets). You cannot enter 4 arguments in the function I wrote, only two tuples/lists.